# Is there a mature OpenGL library for Pharo 2.0?

Tags: pharo

The answer in http://book.pharo-project.org/book/LanguageAndLibraries/3DGraphicsAndOpenGL/ is too outdated.

Comment: should work on Ubuntu 12.10 or later

Answer (score 3):

For Pharo 2.0 and OpenGL, there is a binding package called NBOpenGL.

Check it out here:

http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~PharoExtras/NBOpenGL

you can install it:

```
Gofer it
    smalltalkhubUser: 'PharoExtras' project: 'NBOpenGL';
    configuration;
    load.
(ConfigurationOfNBOpenGL project version: '2.0') load.
```

In my mac, it works out of the box, but it lacks some documentation. 
I found one example:

```
GLTTRenderingDemo new openInWorld.
```

And well, since is just an OpenGL binding, graphic programmers should be confortable with it :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10, GLTRenderingDemo raises Error: 'function unavailable' .
It seems that nobody is using Smalltalk on Ubuntu for 3D nowadays.

Comment: The code that raises error is
    NBGIxAPI>>queryExtension: display errorBase: errorBase eventBase: eventBase
     <primitive: #primitiveNativeCall module: #NativeBoostPlugin>
    
     ^ self call: #( bool glXQueryExtension ( Display "*"display , int * errorBase, int * eventBase ) )

Comment: you need 32bits libraries... have you checked that?

Comment: you also need to ensure the path to your opengl lib in settings>ffi is correct - it will be something like /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Athens](http://code.google.com/p/pharo/wiki/Athens). Here is [demo](http://www.pharocasts.com/2012/06/athens-and-native-boost-at-work.html)